# CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials expiry

Tags: c#, .net, system.net.httpwebrequest, defaultnetworkcredentials

When running a web app or windows service and making web requests to other sites, I specify the credentials this way:

```
var test = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
test.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

This works until there has been an outage on the site for an extended period of time (several hours). Once the site is available and accessible, the following error is generated for each connection attempt until the windows service is restarted.

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503)
>   Server Unavailable.

What would be the best way to get around this? It's difficult to deal with because a small outage on a site can happen at any point, and I need to be able to log into the server and restart the application freely in order for regular business to resume.

**edit**: Actually, the exception that is usually repeated until I restart the service is usually, but not always:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Sorry about that.

Comment: That's a *server-side* error. It has nothing to do with credential expiration. It means the server is dead. Check the service's logs for the full exception.

Comment: How do you call this code? From the docs ` For ASP.NET applications, the default network credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user, or the user being impersonated`. *Are* you using impersonation? Have you tried logging out and logging in again?

Comment: The server is not dead at the time that I am still receiving these errors. When the server is down for an hour and 5-10 attempts are made to access it, I receive the error and I expect it.. because once the site is accessible again, the error stops occurring. When the site is down for multiple hours (4-5), I receive the errors, and I expect it. However, when the site comes back up at that time, I should not still receive these errors. They go away immediately when I restart the windows service. That's why it feels as though something in the app retains cached information.

Comment: I call it in a windows service that has service account credentials stored in the logon details of the windows service. Everything works fine for weeks on end until an extended outage occurs. There is no impersonation involved. 

**I added more information.